# Css flex box 3-column alignment

Tags: css, flexbox

I am a beginner in css and I'm practicing with different designs to get used to using different css properties and flex box especially. I have created the following 3-column layout (with the design from frontendmentor.io). I'm not sure if the issue I'm having is with all screen sizes but at least on my 14inch monitor.... the left-hand column h1 (Sedans) is not aligned with the others.
[Display of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYkm9.png)
All 3 columns' content is set with display flex, flex direction column. I'm still new, so I feel like I'm missing fundamental knowledge to understand what's wrong here.
See the page on github pages: https://yishairose.github.io/3-column-preview/
Code: https://github.com/yishairose/3-column-preview
Html:

```
 <div class="container">
<section class="sedans">
  <img src="images/icon-sedans.svg" alt="">
  <h1>Sedans</h1>
  <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city
    or on your next road trip.</p>
  <a href="" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
</section>
<section class="suv">
  <img src="images/icon-suvs.svg" alt="">
  <h1>SUVs</h1>
  <p> An SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation
    and off-road adventures.</p>
  <a href="" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
</section>
<section class="luxury">
  <img src="images/icon-luxury.svg" alt="">
  <h1>Luxury</h1>
  <p>Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury
    rental and arrive in style.</p>
  <a href="" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
</section>
```

The css for that section:

```
.container {
display: flex;
margin: auto;
height: 60vh;
width: 75%;
}

.container section {

padding: 20px 30px;
color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: start;
justify-content: space-evenly;

}



h1 {

text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Big Shoulders Display', cursive;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 2em;
}
```

I am expecting that all three columns should be perfectly aligned. I haven't yet adjusted the page for mobile devices, I'm currently working on desktop display.
Currently when I reduce screen size significantly the content goes out of the container, which I'm also not sure if that's because I've used flex box incorrectly or just because I still need to use media query.

Comment: You have set `justify-content: space-evenly` for your sections, so if the paragraph text runs longer in one column than in another, that will of course also move the position of the h1 then.